# Django template blocks: how can i reuse them and how do i pass HTML into them?

Tags: django, django-templates, template-engine

Being a frontend dev familiar with Ruby, i'm trying to learn Django templating system.

It appears to be an inside-out version of what i'm used to. I struggle to comprehend its reverse ideology: instead of declaring reusable blocks and including them where necessary, in Django you mark some parts of your template as overridable.

Here are two things that i don't understand about this.

1. With Ruby's Padrino, i would declare a *partial* (a reusable snippet of templated HTML) and then include it in **multiple** places. Wherever i call it, it would output its HTML.

   According to Django's [templating documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#template-inheritance), each *block* can be used on a page only **once**: *Finally, note that you can’t define multiple block tags with the same name in the same template.*
2. Another feature of Padrino that i find extermely useful is that partials can accept HTML and output (yield) it in a certain place inside them. Below are a couple examples, one for Padrino and one for Jade.

   Please note that partails HTML not as a string (awkwardly passed via an argument) but in a template language via nesting.

### Padrino (Ruby) example

With Padrino i can pass HTML template code into partials:

**_container.erb**

```
<div class="container <%= myclass %>">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**layout.erb**

```
<%= partial 'container', locals: { myclass: 'container--header' } do %>
  <h1><%= Sitename %></h1>
  <p>Welcome to my humble place</p>
<% end %>
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<div class="container container--header">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <h1>Sitename</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my humble place</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Jade example

In Jade, partials are called mixins and are processed directly by the template engine rather than the backend framework:

**Jade source**

```
mixin article(title)
  .article
    .article-wrapper
      h1= title
      if block
        block
      else
        p No content provided

+article('Hello world')
  p This is my
  p Amazing article
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>This is my</p>
    <p>Amazing article</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Is it possible with Django?

Questions:

1. How do i reuse a block multiple times in Django? I would like to declare a snippet of template code and include it in multiple places on the page.
2. How do i pass HTML (template code) into a block? I would like to reuse it with different content.

The use case that i'm trying to cover is a reusable partial/mixin/block that would serve as a container wrapper for each section of the site.

Note that with Padrino, i can even make the partial in such a way that it will let me choose which wrapper tag (div, nav, header...) should be used for each instance of the partial, by passing an argument when including the partial:

```
<% partial 'container', myclass: 'container--header', tag: 'nav' %>
```

I wonder how to do that with Django.

In your answer, please comment on whether it is possible with both a) basic Django functionality; b) some Django extensions.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not familiar with Padrino, so I’m not 100% sure I understand what you’re looking for.

However, Django template blocks definitely aren’t the equivalent of Padrino’s partials. From your description, I think the equivalent would be [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/).

In outline, to create a custom template tag, you:

1. Create a templatetags module within your Django app, with a file in it to contain the Python code for the tags e.g.

   ```
   yourapp/
       models.py
       templatetags/
           __init__.py
           mytemplatetags.py
   ```
2. Within that file, create a variable called `register` that’s an instance of `django.template.Library`:

   ```
   # mytemplatetags.py

   from django import template

   register = template.Library()
   ```
3. Within that file, write a function for each custom tag that you want.

For a tag that includes a template snippet, you’d want to write an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Inclusion tags can take arguments, which could include HTML (but only as a string).